# First order IIR high pass filter

Tags: digital-filters

The cutoff frequency is 0.05 Hz. The DC offset of the signal is 5mv. How to determine when the signal will stabilise to the baseline?

Comment: Hi Likhitha- Welcome to DSP.SE! You would need to be a lot more specific in your question, and to show all your work and what research you have done to have the best chance of getting help (What is the background and purpose of your question- is this a homework problem?). As a hint, write out the equation for the time response of a general first order system; it should be an exponential decay going from 5 mv to 0. You will also need to define "stabilise"; often this is given as some criteria to be within x% of 0, such as the 99% settling time, or 90% settling time etc. Good luck!

Comment: This filter is used to remove the basline wandering of the signal.I am using a library prodived by an extenal party.So i don't know the equations and all those stuff.I have to measure the time the signal takes to remove the baseline drift if we apply a 5mv dc offset.